# Adding/updating skeleton files after user creation

Tags: linux, redhat, user-management

#### Background

RedHat 7 (and 6) servers with multiple application servers (shared binaries).

We set up separate user accounts when adding applications servers with $HOME = appserver_root. The installation however demands that the target directory does not exist.

#### So we:

- Create the user without creating the home directory
- Install the server into (and creating) the home directory
- Reset the permissions of the home directory

This process will not set up the skeleton files, i.e. copy /etc/skel/

#### Question

We can simply copy /etc/skel/.*, but is there a tooled way - command - which will do this?

I'd prefer using a standard tool instead of making a guess, or parsing /etc/default/useradd for the correct SKEL path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to adjust your procedure to something like this:

1. Create the user normally, allowing the homedir to be created and
   populated with the skeleton files in the "standard" way
2. Rename the homedir to something else, `username.skeleton` for example
3. Install the server into the home directory (creating a new homedir)
4. Reset the permissions of the home directory
5. Carefully merge into the homedir the config files from the `username.skeleton` dir (there can be conflicts if the server installation creates its own config files), or simply copy over the files already merged in previous identical installations, if available.

I'm using a similar procedure for my own homedir when installing a new OS version because my existing config files from the older OS version may negatively impact the newer app versions and the new skeleton files are missing my customisations - they need to be merged.

Comment: Thanks. However, with this approach we still will be doing a fair amount of adaptations.

Comment: As there are no tooled ways of doing this I think this is the correct answer since you make sure you get the correct files. I'll accept this answer.